# How to make array intersect in php?

Tags: php

This is my two arrays:

```
$head_office = array(600,400,534,678,601,90);
$Sb_office = array(600,400,530,678,600,90,84);
```

My desire output:

```
array(600,400,678,90);
```

I am trying:

```
print_r(array_intersect($Sb_office,$head_office));
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 600 [1] => 400 [3] => 678 [4] => 600 [5] => 90 )
```

How can I avoid the value 600 ?

NB: I am not removing duplicate values. I want to get matched values between 2 arrays.

Comment: Assuming that you mean you want to avoid ___duplicating___ the value 600, then there's a magic little function called [array_unique()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php): `print_r(arry_unique(array_intersect($Sb_office,$head_office)));`

Comment: yes it brings one value removing duplicate values. But I want to get matched value between my two arrays. Here, $head_office has only one 600. So after intersect result should have one 600.  It is not removing duplicate values.

Comment: Swap $Sb_office and $head_office in array_intersect. The order is important

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_unique()`.

```
$head_office = array(600,400,534,678,601,90);
$Sb_office = array(600,400,530,678,600,90,84);

print_r(array_unique(array_intersect($Sb_office,$head_office)));
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => 600 [1] => 400 [3] => 678 [5] => 90 )
```

Comment: yes it brings one value removing duplicate values. But I want to get matched value between my two arrays. Here, $head_office has only one 600. So after intersect result should have one 600. It is not removing duplicate values

Comment: @AdamSmith Why does this not work for you? It seems to work fine.

Comment: yes I am trying to explain it that its working with both array_unique() ans assoc() what is the diffrence in oputput? thanks. @CodeGodie

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Additionally you can use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to alter the keys of new array.

```
$head_office = array(600,400,534,678,601,90);
$Sb_office = array(600,400,530,678,600,90,84);

print_r(array_values(array_unique(array_intersect($Sb_office,$head_office))));
```

OUTPUT

> Array ( [0] => 600 [1] => 400 [2] => 678 [3] => 90 )

Answer (score 0):

It seams that you want to avoid duplicate value 600. you can do it using **array_unique()** like below

```
print_r(arry_unique(array_intersect($Sb_office,$head_office)));
```

Comment: no I am not removing duplicate values. I want to get matched values between 2 arrays

Answer (score 0):

**Swap $head_office and $Sb_office**

```
<?php
$head_office = array(600,400,534,678,601,90);
$Sb_office   = array(600,400,530,678,600,90,84);

print_r( array_intersect($head_office, $Sb_office) );
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 600
    [1] => 400
    [3] => 678
    [5] => 90
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have gotten a partial answer:

```
print_r( array_intersect_assoc($head_office, $Sb_office) );
```

Comment: Almost! assoc also compares the indexes, which would fail if the values are available in both arrays but on different positions.

Comment: See last my comment to your question.

Comment: You need to delete this answer and instead _edit_ your original post to add any more info.